# CentOS Text Only - Add Network Adapter

Tags: centos, network-adapter

Added another network adapter to my CentOS (minimal) VM in VMWare Workstation 8.

I've rebooted and obviously the OS doesn't recognise the new adapter.

How do I add / configure it to recognise the new adapter (for instance, give it a name `eth1` and IP `10.1.0.1`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure the OS doesn't recognize it? It probably recognizes it but it isn't configured to do anything.

If you already have `eth0`, try (as **root**):

`ifconfig eth1 up`

If that works, then the kernel successfully detected the adapter and created a device node for it, but the userspace tools don't currently assign an IP to it.

You can find documentation on modifying the network scripts, which bring up and take down network interfaces at boot and when changing runlevels, [here (Red Hat documentation)](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s1-networkscripts-control.html).

Comment: I did an `ifup eth1` and got an error back about an interface not being available. `ifconfig eth1 up` did the trick! Thank you!